# Netbeans после интерполяции в селекторе с ссылкой на родителя не подсвечивается синтаксис SCSS. Как исправить? Или как настроить плагин SCSS Support?

Tags: netbeans, sass, scss

Есть такой код:

```
.dis-thing {
    @for $i from 0 through 4 {
        &__text_lvl_#{$i+1} {
            font-size: 26px - 2 * $i;
        }
    }
}
```

После него не подсвечивается синтаксис SCSS. Как будто отключен плагин. 
Если заменю & на .dis-thing, то все работает.
Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это исправить?

Я попробовал скачать другой плагин (не родной) для SCSS. Вот этот:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/34929/scss-support

Здесь такой проблемы нет. Однако есть другая. Если я открыл скобки {} и поставил курсор между ними и нажал Enter, то мой селектор автоматически передвигается на 1 tab вправо. 
Вот скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать, чтобы автоматически не передвигался?

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но удивило, что netbeans ещё в ходу. Я не так давно смотрел наличие и даты обновление некоторых плагинов, и понял, что платформа скорее заброшена. Не хотите попробовать webstorm?

Comment: Я уже к Netbeans привык.